# Accessing headers in Spotify api call response

Tags: angularjs, http, spotify

I am  building an app that uses the Spotify api. At the moment a user can paste in tracks and get information for each track. One of my playlists has 500 tracks so the browser makes 500 calls in quick succession. This violates the api rate limits and I get an error with these headers back:

```
HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 23 Jan 2016 11:47:52 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=600
Retry-After: 7
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Max-Age: 604800
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

I am tying to access the `Retry-After` header but in my code I use the `headers()` function from the angular `$http` service and I get an empty object. My code cannot see any of the headers.

All of the questions that I have read about accessing headers here point to changing the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` returned by the server to allow the client to get the headers. As I am not in control of the Spotify server I obviously can't change this.

Looking at the headers above it seems that I will never be able to access the `Retry-After` header as it is not included in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` list.

Is there anything I can do to access this header? I did see something about changing defaults in the `$httpProvider` service but I couldn't seem to get that to work.

In case it is relevant here are my request headers:

```
GET /v1/tracks/1KsI8NEeAna8ZIdojI3FiT HTTP/1.1
Host: api.spotify.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:63342
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:63342/SpotifyExportTool/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

My request looks like this:

```
return Rx.Observable.fromPromise<IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<ITrackDetails>>(this.$http.get( `https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/${trackId}` ))
    .retry(3)
    .catch( (error) => {
        var headers: any = error.headers();
        return Rx.Observable.throw<ITrackDetails>( <ITrackError>{ id: trackId, error: error } );
    } )
    .pluck<ITrackDetails>( "data" );
```

the headers var is always an empty object. error here is a response object as detailed [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

I have managed to recreate this in [Js bin](https://jsbin.com/picewugexo/edit?html,js,console). This uses no angular code or anything other than a XMLHttpRequest:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0YGQ3hZcRLC5YX7o0hdmHg", false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();

console.log(req.status)
console.log(headers)
```

I still get nothing in the headers for the error response. Below you can see the output for a successful request followed by the output from an error:
[image]

Comment: Can you pass a snippet of your request? Mainly how you handle the response.

Comment: have added details of the call and error handling.

Comment: I think there might be an issue with the library that you use. What does the `error` contain?

Comment: I am using angular. the response object is detailed here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: I think that angular is doing ok as I get headers on a successful response:
headers: {"content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","cache-control":"public, max-age=7200"}

Comment: yes, I managed to recreate without angular.

Comment: I tried to do something similar using only angular and it worked just fine, I got the headers it seems that `Rx` is your problem.

Comment: The last example uses no libraries at all. I think Spotify if the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should fetch several tracks in one request. https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-several-tracks/

It doesn't help you with the problem you have when are rate limited, but it will be faster and might stop you from becoming rate limited.

Comment: Yes I know, I am going to authorise the user and get users playlists so this will be unnecessary but I'm doing this as a learning exercise so want to know why this isn't working. Thanks for the answer anyway.